# ant target vssget is not working

Tags: java, ant, visual-sourcesafe

when I run the ant target vssbuild it gives following error.

```
D:\release>ant vssbuild Buildfile:
build.xml

vssbuild:    [vssget] 'ss' is not
recognized as an internal or external
command,    [vssget] operable program
or batch file.

BUILD FAILED
D:\release\build.xml:141:
Failed executi ng: ss Get $(project)
-GLD:\release\$(lo
calpath) -I-  -R  
-Y$(vssusername),**************   With a return code of 1
```

I have set the system path to ss.exe.

below I have shown my ant target.

```
<property name="localpath" value="checkout" />
    <property name="project" value="$/NewGen/NextGenComm" />
    <property name="vssusername" value ="ganukep" />
    <property name="vsspassword" value ="123"/>
    <property name="projectlabel" value = "2011.05.20_V1.0.0" />
    <target name="vssbuild"> 
        <vssget vsspath="$(project)" 
              localpath="$(localpath)" 
              recursive="true" 
              login="$(vssusername),$(vsspassword)"
        />     
     </target>
```

Can some one pls help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you get a CreateProcesss IOError=2 when running these, it means that ss.exe was not found. Check to see if you can run it from the command line -you may need to alter your path, or set the ssdir property.

It may not be the same error but it shows what needs to be done so that ant can find `ss.exe`. I'd try setting the `ssdir` property next (if the system path trick didn't help).

And you may want to `<echo>` the `PATH` variable in your build script - maybe `ant` sees some different content.